# API Level Caching in Ektron

Tags: ektron

I am working in Ektron 8.6.

Does anyone know how API level caching is managed in ektron?
Is there is any config settings to manage API level caching?(web.config or any other config files).Whether API level caching is enabled by default?Is it different in the previous version(Ektron 8.5)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting in version 8.5, Ektron introduced a caching layer that sits beneath its Framework APIs. It is configurable (enable, disable, set ttl, etc) and extensible (provider based so you can implement providers for various cache servers like Reddis, etc).

It is not enabled by default. By default, each API call ultimately hits the database (or the search index). Since this is new in version 8.5+, older versions of Ektron do not have any sort of built-in API level caching, though can obviously take advantage of any standard .NET caching you'd want to create on your own.

Here's a technical webinar that goes into detail on the API level caching in v8.5+. The piece relevant to your question starts at 26:25, but I'd watch the whole thing if you haven't seen it already.

http://www.ektron.com/Webinars/Details/Optimize-Site-Performance-through-Caching/

The default Ektron cache provider uses in-memory / in-proc application scope storage. Once you use that, you may want to take a look at this open source project which implements a 3rd party cache provider for Redis. You can use this as is, or us it as the stub for your own cache provider for another system, or just stick with the OOB in-proc cache provider.

https://github.com/ektron/EktronContrib/blob/master/README.md

Bill